# How many interface we can declare within a class in java/android

Tags: java, android, interface

How many interface we can declare within a class.

Is this number **65535**? if yes then why? if no, what is the limit and why?

Something like:

```
public class GenericModelLinker {
   public interface Link {
      Object getProperty(IAdaptable n);
      void setProperty(IAdaptable n, Object value);
   }
 // .........so on
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: From where did you get that number `65535` ? Do you have a reference for that ?

Comment: yes i have read some articles on stackoverflow regarding interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! According to the Official [Specifications](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.11) of the Java Virtual Machine. It seems the fields, methods and nested types info are each stored in some kind of an structure that has a limited size.

If you're asking Why `65535` ? Simply because :

> it is the highest number which can be represented by an unsigned
>   16-bit binary number

### 4.11. Limitations of the Java Virtual Machine

> The following limitations of the Java Virtual Machine are implicit in
>   the class file format:
>
> The per-class or per-interface constant pool is limited to 65535
>   entries by the 16-bit constant_pool_count field of the ClassFile
>   structure (§4.1). This acts as an internal limit on the total
>   complexity of a single class or interface.
>
> The number of fields that may be declared by a class or interface is
>   limited to 65535 by the size of the fields_count item of the ClassFile
>   structure (§4.1).
>
> Note that the value of the fields_count item of the ClassFile
>   structure does not include fields that are inherited from superclasses
>   or superinterfaces.
>
> The number of methods that may be declared by a class or interface is
>   limited to 65535 by the size of the methods_count item of the
>   ClassFile structure (§4.1).
>
> Note that the value of the methods_count item of the ClassFile
>   structure does not include methods that are inherited from
>   superclasses or superinterfaces.
>
> The number of direct superinterfaces of a class or interface is
>   limited to 65535 by the size of the interfaces_count item of the
>   ClassFile structure (§4.1).
>
> The greatest number of local variables in the local variables array of
>   a frame created upon invocation of a method (§2.6) is limited to 65535
>   by the size of the max_locals item of the Code attribute (§4.7.3)
>   giving the code of the method, and by the 16-bit local variable
>   indexing of the Java Virtual Machine instruction set.
>
> Note that values of type long and double are each considered to
>   reserve two local variables and contribute two units toward the
>   max_locals value, so use of local variables of those types further
>   reduces this limit.
>
> The size of an operand stack in a frame (§2.6) is limited to 65535
>   values by the max_stack field of the Code attribute (§4.7.3).
>
> Note that values of type long and double are each considered to
>   contribute two units toward the max_stack value, so use of values of
>   these types on the operand stack further reduces this limit.
>
> The number of method parameters is limited to 255 by the definition of
>   a method descriptor (§4.3.3), where the limit includes one unit for
>   this in the case of instance or interface method invocations.
>
> Note that a method descriptor is defined in terms of a notion of
>   method parameter length in which a parameter of type long or double
>   contributes two units to the length, so parameters of these types
>   further reduce the limit.
>
> The length of field and method names, field and method descriptors,
>   and other constant string values (including those referenced by
>   ConstantValue (§4.7.2) attributes) is limited to 65535 characters by
>   the 16-bit unsigned length item of the CONSTANT_Utf8_info structure
>   (§4.4.7).
>
> Note that the limit is on the number of bytes in the encoding and not
>   on the number of encoded characters. UTF-8 encodes some characters
>   using two or three bytes. Thus, strings incorporating multibyte
>   characters are further constrained.
>
> The number of dimensions in an array is limited to 255 by the size of
>   the dimensions opcode of the multianewarray instruction and by the
>   constraints imposed on the multianewarray, anewarray, and newarray
>   instructions (§4.9.1, §4.9.2).

Comment: Please also mention the source URL for this information.

Comment: @shriduttkothari it is already mentioned. Click on `Specifications` at the first line.